How can you tell which branch and commit of the source repository a package installed in Pharo is based on?
In other words do Pharo images have the information about the branches and commits the packages they contain?
Is there some way to know which version is in the image compared with which one is in the repository?
Are there commands to query for the information either from Iceberg or Metacello?
For instance when I browse the packages in Iceberg I can see entries like Uncommitted changes, Not loaded, Detached HEAD and Detached working copy.

As can be seen at the bottom the picture, the Pharo image I'm using was built from commit 28169ae on the Pharo10 branch and it also says so in the About | Help menu.
Does Uncommitted changes mean there are updates in the repo which have not been incorporated in the image, or possibly vice versa?
I can't remember updating Pharo itself, so I can only assume that some other packages I installed must have pulled them in.
